# Office Add-in sets the Start Document to Read-Only on every launch

Tags: office-js, excel-addins

I am trying to write a custom Excel addin using OfficeJS. I have set a Start Document in my Addin project, so that when I launch Excel from Visual Studio, it automatically opens my test document.

The problem is, Excel ends up marking my file as read-only, which causes my add-in not to function.

If I open the file directly from Explorer, it opens correctly, but when launched from Visual Studio, the "Read-Only" flag is set to true in the file's properties. No matter many times I clear the flag, or save the document to a new location, this flag always gets set.

Even if I use [New Excel Workbook] as my Start Document, the blank workbook is still set as Read-Only.

Is there any way to disable or work around this functionality in Excel?

Comment: OfficeJS (nor web add-ins in general) is not related to making Excel files read-only. That's more security related question and belongs to super user site instead.

Comment: I feel like I need to disagree. It's the Excel addin tooling in Visual Studio that is marking the file as read-only. I can open/modify the file outside of Visual studio without any issue, but when the file is opened by Visual Studio, it gets flagged as read-only.

Comment: @Dave, did you find the solution to the file being read-only?  I'm having same issue.

Comment: @BobDuffett, I don't entirely remember my solution, but I was able to get it to work. I remember that despite the file being marked as read only, I eventually *was* able to modify it using Office JS. I think the solution just ended up being a bug in my code.